# How to combine 100+ MP3's in to one concatenated MP3?

Tags: batch, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to join MP3 files?](https://superuser.com/questions/67207/how-to-join-mp3-files)

I have over 100 MP3's in a folder that I am viewing in Windows Explorer and they are all sorted. However, to manually combine them in source forge I have to splice each one individually. Is there any batch tool available where I could drag all these files in to a program and have it output the spliced version?

Thanks

Comment: A search for "batch join mp3" shows up quite a few possibilities. I haven't used any so I can't recommend one. All I can suggest is you research a few and find one you like. Also see - http://superuser.com/questions/67207/how-to-join-mp3-files

Comment: What is "source forge"?

Answer (score -1):

http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php

try that.

or maybe avidemux.

Comment: That is an answer for the opposite question - how can I **split** mp3 files, while the question is about **combining** mp3 files.